# Shorten name of types diplayed in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to shorten the displayed names in VS when hovering over some method, constructor etc., so instead of displaying the popup with System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable there will be a popup with just an IEnumerable ?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to say that **NO** there is no such way. It shows all the things to make it clear rather then increasing the confusion.

Comment: It makes a lot of noise, especially when dealing with generic class's constructor, that takes a Func<> as a parameter which returns some generic class etc. It's very hard to understand the signature then.

Comment: @user3284063:- I do understand but I am afraid as there is no such way to accomplish that. You have to live with that :)